# Ruby: Does a locked object stay locked if an exception occurs inside it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, locking

I am using `with_lock` to lock the block of instruction where I am going to call `update_all`. If an exception is raised inside the block, does a locked object stay locked?

For example, validator:handle_conflict raise the exception `ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError`, will `with_lock` release the lock? If it doesn't release lock, how to release the lock when exception is raised?

```
attr_accessible :original_updated_at

def original_updated_at
   @original_updated_at || updated_at.to_f
end

validate :handle_conflict, only: :update_all


  def set_total_and_buckets_used
    begin
      /////

      else
        self.with_lock do
          self.reload
          attributes["updated_at"] = Time.now.utc
          Product.where(:id => self.id).update_all(attributes)
          self.attributes = attributes
        end
      end
    rescue ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError => e
      if tries < MAX_RETRIES
        tries += 1
        sleep(1 + tries)
        retry
      else
        raise Exception.new(timeout.inspect)
      end
    end
    attributes
  end


  def handle_conflict
    if self.updated_at.to_f > original_updated_at
      @original_updated_at = nil
      raise ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError.new("Car is changed while you were editing")
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [implementation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html#method-i-with_lock), you can see that `with_lock` wraps your block into a transaction. So, when an exception is raised in you block, your transaction is rollbacked and your lock released.

By the way:

- locking your record ensures you that you won't have to deal with a StaleObjectError.
- I don't think your code work works, why don't you just update your model:

`self.with_lock do
   update_your_attributes
   self.save
 end`

Comment: I updated question with code for `original_updated_at`. If you check in the code I am using `handle_conflict` which is throwing an exception `ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError. ` if `self.updated_at.to_f > original_updated_at` is true. I updated